# Como gerar Matriz-Adjacente de uma BFS a partir de um arquivo txt? C++

Tags: c++, arquivo, matriz, grafo

Estou usando o CodeBlocks.

Eu tenho um arquivo .txt que representa um labirinto, tudo que está depois do `:` são salas:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A primeira linha do arquivo mostra a coordenada de inicio, que nesse caso é `AS`. Toda letra `w` representa uma parede. Então a minha BFS tem como nó inicial (ou raiz inicial) o `AS`.

Para representar esse labirinto em um grafo ficaria assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu tenho que representar esse grafo em uma matriz de adjacência. E eu travei nessa parte, que tenho de gerar essa matriz, pois pra fazer a BFS o código precisa conhecer o grafo. Não consegui pensar em uma maneira de representar essa matriz adjacente lendo esse arquivo, por favor, qualquer sugestão, ideias, material, me ajudaria bastante.

Obs: Meu código já consegue obter e armazenar o labirinto em uma matriz, sem as letras antes dos `:` e sem a coordenada inicial. Tenho o labirinto completo em uma matriz. Dizer quem é vizinho de quem e gerar o grafo é o que eu não estou conseguindo fazer.

Comment: @nbro, sua suposição está correta, são apenas nomes para cada uma das salas do labirinto. As siglas antes do `:` é como uma numeração, pois nesse problema existem salas que contém joias, e para indicar que uma sala contém uma joia é feito o seguinte:


`AN: AO S AM BI`
`*AO: AP T AN BJ`
`AP: w U AO BK`

Repare que em `*AO:` existe o caractere `*`, e ele indica que em todas as salas posteriores de nome `AO` existem joias.

No caso, preciso dizer esses critérios para minha BFS: Trace o melhor caminho para saída, pegando todas as joias e não passando por sala de nome `w`. Continua...

Comment: Continuação... Porém, pra fazer a BFS eu tenho que ter o grafo, que diz quem é vizinho de quem, e essa parte que não consigo resolver, como posso criar o grafo, ou seja, a matriz adjacente, com todas as relações das salas? Por favor, qualquer dica ou sugestão vai me ajudar muito.

Comment: @nbro Todos os grafos que trabalhei, aplicados nos algoritmos de busca, eram informados a mão, pois eram pequenos. Nunca trabalhei com algoritmos de busca onde devemos gerar o grafo a partir do algoritmo. Não conheço a "adjacent list".

Comment: @nbro, Interessante, vou seguir sua sugestão. Pesquisarei sobre Nós e listas adjacentes e tentarei isso. Obrigado pela sugestão e pela dica, assim que obtiver resultados eu atualizo o post aqui.

Answer (score 1):

Minha dica é criar sua matriz de adjacência como uma matriz de tamanho 150x150 e utilizar o valor ASCII dos caracteres como posições na matriz.

Pegando a linha `A: B W W V` do seu arquivo como exemplo, seu primeiro passo é ignorar o `W`, afinal ele não acrescenta informação alguma ao grafo. Em seguida você converte as letras para seus respectivos valores na [tabela ASCII](http://ic.unicamp.br/~everton/aulas/hardware/tabelaASCII.pdf). `A` vira `65`, `B 66` e `V 86`. Então você usa esses valores como índices em sua matriz de adjacência: a linha `65` da matriz teria todos seus valores como `0` (indicando ausência de conexão com outros nós), exceto pelas colunas `66` e `86`, onde o valor seria `1`, indicando conexão com os nós `B` e `V`, respectivamente.

E para tratar os casos especiais em que o "nome" do nó é o conjunto de duas letras, basta somar o valor ASCII de ambas. Exemplo: `AS` vira `148` (`65 + 83`).